# Java FX: Detected [iscc.exe] version 0 but version 5 is required. Bundler EXE Installer skipped because of a configuration problem

Tags: java, javafx, inno-setup

I build a Java FX application, and now trying to convert into execution file.exe
But tried to build it shows the following error in bold. But I have installed Inno Setup 6 software and also set the environment path. But still, error persists.

```
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
Detected [iscc.exe] version 0 but version 5 is required.
Bundler EXE Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: Can not find Inno Setup Compiler (iscc.exe).  
Advice to fix:   Download Inno Setup 5 or later from http://www.jrsoftware.org and add it to the PATH.
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
Detected [iscc.exe] version 0 but version 5 is required.
Bundler EXE Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: Can not find Inno Setup Compiler (iscc.exe).  
Advice to fix:   Download Inno Setup 5 or later from http://www.jrsoftware.org and add it to the PATH.
```

BUILD.XML

```xml
<target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
    <fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}"
               nativeBundles="exe"
               outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
        <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="lib/*.jar"/>
        </fx:resources>
        <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
    </fx:deploy>
</target>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java FX looks for pattern `Inno Setup (\\d+.?\\d*)` in `iscc /?` output.

While Inno Setup 5 prints this:

> Inno Setup 5 Command-Line Compiler

Inno Setup 6 before 6.0.3 omitted the version number:

> Inno Setup Command-Line Compiler

That's why you get

> Detected [iscc.exe] version 0 but version 5 is required.

---

Make sure you have the latest version of Inno Setup 6, as this [got "fixed" in 6.0.3](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/commit/9ae04dc6d11c746d0ba836d8e83499b8f96b523f).

Answer (score 4):

I used a Hex-Editor to change the output of iscc.exe. It now prints:

> Inno Setup 6 mmand-Line Compiler

This is matching the pattern and the compiler runs fine

Comment: inside the iscc.exe offset 000A7190, as a hex editor I'm using HxD. Search for "Command" with Unicode string enabled